# Ubuntu can't ping external

Tags: networking, server

from yesterday I've this annoying issue, I can't ping external from ubuntu 20.04.5

```
PING google.it (142.251.36.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.it ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2041ms
```

nslookup

```
> www.google.it
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.it
Address: 142.251.36.35
Name:   www.google.it
Address: 2a00:1450:400e:811::2003
>
```

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:44:ef:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet **.**.2.4/23 brd **.**.3.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fe44:ef1d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search reddog.microsoft.com
```

sudo iptables -L

```
[sudo] password for crawler-admin:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any ideas?

Thanks to all

Comment: Can you add the output of `ip route` to the question?